# Como Agregar Referencia Namespace "System.Windows.Forms" en VS CODE, medieante la terminal de comandos (CLI)?

Tags: c#, .net, vscode, .net-core, dotnetcore

Su gentil ayuda en la resolución de un inconveniente al momento de querer utilizar la directiva
"using" junto con la declaración del espacio de nombres "System.Windows.Forms", la misma
que me arroja que error de no encontrarse en dicha librería.

Estuve investigando por varias horas y solo encontré soluciones que se aplican al IDE de "VS Community", sin embargo al interar usar los comandos "dotnet" o "dotnet nuget" y todas sus variantes no funciona y no trae el paquete o la refencia necesaria para utilizar la clase "Forms".

Su amable ayuda ya he intentado todas las variantes posibles para logar la refencia a dicha clase, pero no lo he logrado; reiterando es en VS Code.

```
C:\Users\User\L2_ScriptsProjects\PR02_CSharp\Cs01_ConsoleApp>dotnet add Cs01_ConsoleApp.csproj package System.Windows.Forms
  Determinando los proyectos que se van a restaurar...
  Writing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpA782.tmp
info : Agregando PackageReference para el paquete "System.Windows.Forms" al proyecto "Cs01_ConsoleApp.csproj".
info :   GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/system.windows.forms/index.json
info :   OK https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/system.windows.forms/index.json 192 ms
info :   CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/system.windows.forms/index.json
error: No hay ninguna versión disponible para el paquete "System.Windows.Forms".


Usage: NuGet.CommandLine.XPlat.dll package add [options]

Options:
  -h|--help               Show help information
  --force-english-output  Fuerza la aplicación a ejecutarse mediante una referencia cultural invariable basada en el inglés.
  --package               Id. del paquete que se va a agregar.
  --version               Versión del paquete que se agregará.
  -d|--dg-file            Ruta de acceso al archivo de gráficos de dependencia que se usará 
para restaurar la vista previa y comprobar la compatibilidad.
  -p|--project            Ruta de acceso al archivo de proyecto.
  -f|--framework          Los marcos de trabajo para los que se debe agregar la referencia de paquete.
  -n|--no-restore         No realiza la vista previa de restauración y la comprobación de compatibilidad. La referencia de paquete agregada será incondicional.
  -s|--source             Especifica orígenes de paquete NuGet para usar durante la restauración.
  --package-directory     Directorio donde restaurar los paquetes.
  --interactive           Permite usar el comando para bloquear y requerir la acción manual 
para operaciones como la autenticación.
  --prerelease            Permite que se instalen paquetes de versión preliminar.
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Archivo extensión .csproj**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Comando Utilizado:**

`dotnet add Cs01_ConsoleApp.csproj package System.Windows.Forms`

Comment: Agrega en tu `.csproj` dentro del `PropertyGroup` la línea `<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>` y me haces saber si te funciona.

Comment: Si, estimado @JaimeMenéndez, sin embargo creo que al ser projecto de consola no crea o configura el espacio de trabajo de forma adecuada para poder implentar "WPF", y desconozco que otros paquetes u otra configuracion deberia realizar.

Comment: Por lo que opte, en crear otro projecto que soporte "WPF" con el comando del `dotnet new wpf`, y me funciono. Para los que tengan ese inconveniente creo que es mejor crea ese tipo de espacios de trabajo, que intentar arreglaro, ya que al no conocer que paquete se necesitan, se consume demasiado tiempo.

Comment: De todas, formas muchas gracias, si me desmarco ese error de la directiva "using" que aparecia. Saludos